# Can copying site content for a mobile version of the site impact SEO?

Tags: seo

I am thinking about copying our content (text content especially) from our main site (eg: `example.com`) to the mobile version of the site (eg: `m.example.com` or `example.com/m`).

What are the SEO side effects of doing so?

Do SEO experts recommend this practice?

If you have external articles or reference, hope you guys can share here also.

Answer (score 3):

I usually put the same content on both. Apart the fact that the mobile version is of course a bit lighter. But the content is the same.

To avoid duplicate content or other bad thing, I use *Switchboard Tags* ([source](http://searchengineland.com/switchboard-tags-like-canonical-tags-but-for-mobile-seo-127676)).

Basically (sorry this is an image from the previous blog):

[image]

Comment: Google also recommend using the Vary HTTP header when doing this.

Comment: @GDav could you provide a link or something about that?

Comment: @j0k https://developers.google.com/webmasters/smartphone-sites/details

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use CSS to serve your mobile website on the same url? I haven't tried it but I believe it should be possible, you can just have two different css and switch them based on user agent.

Comment: Yeap, that is responsive website. I'm on my way to finish it. :)
Just asking here.